# Responsive columns in Materialize

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, materialize, col

I am working with MaterializeCSS (http://materializecss.com/) and I've been struggling with grid layout.

Let's say I have 4 contents for 4 columns. I want them responsivly break to two lines if the contents of those columns overlaps.

Example:
`[[A][B]] [[C][D]]` <- Each letter represent each content of the column. If those contents starts to overlap, I want them to wrap like this:

```
[[A][B]]
[[C][D]]
```

And also if I resize the window more and A and B or C and D starts to overlap, I want each content on separate "line/row":

```
[A]
[B]
[C]
[D]
```

My code looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col l6 m6 s12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col s6">
                    <img height="200" src="https://www.lg.com/cz/content/img/support/img-dummy-product.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="col s6">
                    <img height="200" src="https://www.lg.com/cz/content/img/support/img-dummy-product.jpg">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col l6 m6 s12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col s6">
                    <div>
                        <i style="color: #4267b2" class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <i style="color: #1da1f2; margin-left:10px" class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="header-col4 col s6">
                    <a href="#" target="_blank">
                        <img height="200" src="https://www.lg.com/cz/content/img/support/img-dummy-product.jpg">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried many ways, but none of my way did solve the problem like I wanted.

Also I would like to have those contents vertically and horizontally center of the parent div.

I managed to achieve that the columns were wrapping like I wanted, except that the third and fourth column were overlapping, beacuse the image was outside of the parent div.

Thanks for any help! 
I really appreciate that!

Answer (score 2):

Hi I am not sure what you want to achieve..

Please see the sample code below.

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col l6 m6 s12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="container col l6">
                    <img height="200" src="https://www.lg.com/cz/content/img/support/img-dummy-product.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="container col l6">
                    <img height="200" src="https://www.lg.com/cz/content/img/support/img-dummy-product.jpg">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col l6 m6 s12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="container col l6">
                    <a href="#" target="_blank">
                        <img height="200" src="https://www.lg.com/cz/content/img/support/img-dummy-product.jpg">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="container header-col4 col l6">
                    <a href="#" target="_blank">
                        <img height="200" src="https://www.lg.com/cz/content/img/support/img-dummy-product.jpg">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I did i change the img parent to col l6 ..

It seems that col s6 is making it overlap the div to each other.

```
                     <div class="container col l6">
                        <a href="#" target="_blank">
                            <img height="200" src="https://www.lg.com/cz/content/img/support/img-dummy-product.jpg">
                        </a>
                    </div>
```

to make those contents vertically and horizontally center of the parent div.
I add a class (.container) in the img parent and add flexbox.

```
.container{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you provide an explanation to go along with code?

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it has the same problem as I mentioned in the comment above. I want to break those contents as I mentioned in my original post. So it's whether 4x1 (4 contents, 1 line), 2x2 or 1x4. Any thoughts? Also centered and prevent overlaps of the contents.

Comment: Hi @Honzys, Please see the edited code.
I'm not sure if that is what you want to achieve, but please give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

> > Example: [[A][B]] [[C][D]] <- Each letter represent each content of
> >     the column. If those contents starts to overlap, I want them to wrap
> >     like this:
> >
> > [[A][B]]
> >     [[C][D]]

I think you should try

```
row
 col l3 m6 s6
```

but just for each div

UPDATE:

```
<div class="col l3 m6 s6"> <-- like this
  <img height="200" src="https://www.lg.com/cz/content/img/support/img-dummy-product.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this doesn't work. When I resize it it breaks it to A, C, D on the first line and B on the second line. What I want, is that if some content overlaps, break it to AB (first "line") CD (second "line")